# Qual o significado da expressão «Ó tempo, volta para trás»?

Tags: significado

Estava numa conversa e disseram: «Ó tempo, volta para trás».

Qual o seu significado e com que intenção é normalmente dita?

Comment: poderia colocar mais partes do diálogo? Apenas com isso, imagino que seja uma vontade de reviver um momento ou ainda um arrependimento.

Comment: Não existe o caso de "normalmente dito" para citar poesia. "Ó tempo" se chama o vocativo, Isso quer dizer que o tempo está sendo tratado como se fosse uma pessoa. Como se o locutor se dirigisse a uma pessoa.  Se usa muito em poesia.

Comment: Ele quer que o tempo regresse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Significa aquilo que está escrito: o locutor sente saudades de épocas passadas e deseja voltar no tempo.  Embora "voltar pra trás" seja considerado um pleonasmo (comparável a "subir pra cima") e raramente seja ouvido em pt-BR, acredito que seja de uso corrente em Portugal. É uma conclusão a que chego, por ter ouvido "voltar pra trás" diversas vezes durante as minhas viagens a Portugal. Temos um bom exemplo da expressão na canção portuguesa [**"Oh Tempo Volta Pra Trás"**](https://www.vagalume.com.br/antonio-mourao/oh-tempo-volta-pra-tras.html) que tornou-se conhecida na voz de [**António Mourão**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_Mour%C3%A3o).

> Oh tempo, volta pra trás,
>
> Trás-me tudo o que eu perdi.
>
> Tem pena e dá-me a vida,
>
> A vida que eu já vivi.
>
> Oh tempo, volta pra trás.
>
> Mata as minhas esperanças vâs.
>
> Vê que até o próprio sol,
>
> Volta todas as manhãs.
>
> Vê que até o próprio sol,
>
> Volta todas as manhãs.